# Click on a Different Link (Randomly) From A List of Links Everytime

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am working on Selenium WebDriver using Java.
I would like to click on a link randomly from a list of available links on a web page every time I go through that page. Here is the detailed scenario.

I am working on a questionnaire which has more than 1 question on a page. For example, a page has 2 questions:

Gender question which has two options. I want to select one randomly. Here are the xpaths:

```
//img[@alt='Male']
//img[@alt='Female']
```

Age question which has 7 options and want to select one or two randomly. Here are the xpaths:

```
//form[@id='question_data']/div/div[3]/div[2]/div
//form[@id='question_data']/div/div[3]/div[3]/div
//form[@id='question_data']/div/div[3]/div[4]/div
//form[@id='question_data']/div/div[3]/div[5]/div
//form[@id='question_data']/div/div[3]/div[6]/div
//form[@id='question_data']/div/div[3]/div[7]/div
//form[@id='question_data']/div/div[3]/div[8/div
```

Comment: Put different xpath options on a list, use `Math.random()` or `Random` class to roll out a random number between 0 and x, then take the xpath on that index from the list? Seems like really basic stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You first get all the available elements, something like:

```
List<WebElement> allElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath(correct_xpath_to_all_elements));
```

And then you pick a random one from the list to click on:

```
allElements[rnd.nextInt(allElements.length)].click();
```

Depending on how exactly you structure your XPath above, you might need to drill further down in the hierarchy before the click. Using your sample code above, something like the following. Although from the sample XPath you provided, I doubt this will work; hopefully it's enough to give you an idea!

```
List<WebElement> allElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//form[@id='question_data']/div/div[3]/div"));
allElements[rnd.nextInt(allElements.length)].findElement(By.xpath("div")).click();
```

Answer (score -1):

Use isDisplayed Function to see which type of answer is getting displayed ( //img or //form ).
Add if-else also you have to handle NoSuchElementFount exception.
Get no of //img or no of //form.
Use Math.random() function and select random answer.